# InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context, using Mono C# compiler

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, initializecomponent

I am using mcs version 2.10.8.1 in Ubuntu 12.04, I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName;
                fileName = dlg.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I compile using the command

```
$ mcs source_code.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll -r:System.Drawing.dll
```

And I receive the error

```
source_code.cs(11,13): error CS0103: The name `InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I've seen many answers to this question in cases using Visual Basic; I would like to know what I should do to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was your C# code originally created in Visual Studio? If so, then you'll probably have a `Form1.Designer.cs` file as well as the file containing the code that you've written by hand. You need to include the file in the command line.

If this *isn't* C# code originally created in Visual Studo, you may not even have an `InitializeComponent` method... but in that case you'll need more code to do anything useful in your form (like creating the button and hooking up its `Click` event).

Comment: I think it must have been imported from MSVS, judging by the `partial` keyword.

Comment: @Antonijn: Well it looks like it *probably* was - but you can easily write partial classes by hand...